# If Python is executed one line at a time, why can it see variables before they're declared?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, scope

```
x = 4
def test():
    print(x)
    x = 2
test()
```

This gives an error because when you go to `print(x)`, it sees that you have `x` declared in the scope of the function `test`, and it tells you you're trying to reference it without having declared it.

I know that if I do `global x` it's no problem, or if I move the print statement...I know.

But I don't understand how the interpreter knows that I have `x` redeclared after the print statement if it goes through the code one line at a time. How can it know what's coming?

There's clearly more to this than I'm aware of.

Comment: it doesn't just parse each line separately... I don't even know of a programming language that does that.

Comment: Well what DOES it do then?

Comment: [Naming and binding](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Comment: @Doorknob: Most traditional BASIC implementations do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Who told you Python is executed one line at a time? Python is executed one bytecode at a time. And that bytecode comes from the compiler, which operates one *statement* at a time. Statements can be multiple lines. And a function definition is a statement.

So, one of the first steps in compiling a function definition is to gather up all of the variables assigned within that function's body. Any variable that's assigned, but doesn't have a `global` or `nonlocal` declaration, is a local.

(As a side note, that function body isn't actually compiled into a function, it's compiled into a `code` object, which gets stashed somewhere, and only run when you call the function, and into some bytecode that builds a `function` object out of that `code` object, which gets run where your function definition occurs in the normal order.)

You can, in fact, see what the compiler made of your function by looking at its members:

```
>>> def foo():
...     global y
...     x=1
...     y=1
>>> foo.__code__.co_varnames
('x',)
```

Then, when it's creating the bytecode for your function body, all variables in `co_varnames` are compiled into local lookups, while the rest are compiled into global lookups:

```
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  4           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (y)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Python does execute instructions one at a time; it's just that a function definition is a *single instruction.* When the Python interpreter encounters a function definition, it compiles the function: first transforming it into an abstract syntax tree (AST), then into bytecode. It's during this process that Python "looks ahead" and sees which variables should be considered local (by scanning the AST and seeing what names are assigned to but not declared global).

When the function is called it's executed an instruction at a time, but the compilation process is free to consider the entire function because it's considered a single operation. This is useful for various optimizations as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at this program as three discrete operations:

```
x = 4           # variable assignment 
def test(): foo # function definition
test()          # function call
```

it makes a bit more sense. The interpreter processes the function definition - and that entails figuring the scope of variables, etc, hence your error.